# Excluding some coordinates of a stl surface

Tags: matlab, stl, coordinates, surface

i have loaded a stl file of a turbine blade into Matlab by using the STLreader. I got the coordinates of all points on the surfaces of the stl model by using the trisurf command (airfoil and foot of the blade). Now I want to focus on the suction sided coordinates of the airfoil. Therefore, I  excluded the points of the blade foot by using the location of the Z-coordinates of the points. Now I want to exclude all points of the airfoil that aren't part of the suction side by using the X- and Y-coordinates of the points but I don't know how to do it. An image is attached to show my problem. I have tried the coordinatetransformation to rotate the X-Y-plane to say that all point with Y smaller than zero are deleted but it doesn't work well because of the curve of the airfoil. I always cut to much or not enough points.
Hopefully, someone can help me.

Yours
Tobias

[turbine blade picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dxx3.png)

Comment: What about **inpolygon()**? If you have data of green boundary you can get points inside of it

Comment: Is it working for a three dimensional room? I thought it would be only for two dimensions.

Comment: Or is it possible to write a loop to check it for each value in z direction?

Comment: **inpolygon** is only for 2D. But maybe you can project your data onto XY?

Comment: Can you tell me how you mean that?

Comment: Can you please attach all data so i can try?